# android - overlapping views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Here's the thing:

I have an EditText and a Button.  The concept is to have the EditText long so that it covers the Button, but the Button is on top.  Let's picture it this way, [] for EditText width, () for Button width.

```
[ EditText        ( Button )]
```

The Button is positioned on the right side within the EditText.  Is it possible?
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you do that? You know text could come **on top** of the Button right? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create a custom view. Below example , there are a botton right of edittect, when you click it, it clear edittext.

clearable_edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
>

<EditText
android:id=”@+id/clearable_edit”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:paddingRight=”35dip”
/>
<Button
android:id=”@+id/clearable_button_clear”
android:layout_width=”30dip”
android:layout_height=”30dip”
android:layout_alignParentRight=”true”
android:background=”@drawable/image_clear”
android:layout_centerVertical=”true”
android:layout_marginRight=”5dip”/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA Code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ClearableEditText extends RelativeLayout
{
LayoutInflater inflater = null;
EditText edit_text;
Button btn_clear;

public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
super(context, attrs, defStyle);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
initViews();
}

public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
super(context, attrs);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
initViews();

}

public ClearableEditText(Context context)
{
super(context);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
initViews();
}

void initViews()
{
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.clearable_edit_text, this, true);
edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clearable_edit);
btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearable_button_clear);
btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
clearText();
showHideClearButton();
}

void clearText()
{
btn_clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
edit_text.setText(“”);
}
});
}

void showHideClearButton()
{
edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (s.length() > 0)
btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
else
btn_clear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
}

public Editable getText()
{
Editable text = edit_text.getText();
return text;
}
}
```

So now our Customized view ClearableEditText is ready now we can use it wherever we need it.
like

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”fill_parent” >

<com.and.ab1209.ClearableEditText
android:id=”@+id/edit_text_clearable”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: putting the two in a relative layout, then setting the width of the EditText to fill_parent and setting the android:layout_alignParentRight to true for the button, actually do the trick. thanks pal, +1 for this.